# Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' - Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, http

I am trying to make a Get request in flutter.
I did everything right but it is showing me the error:  type 'String' is not a sub-type of type 'int'.

I am getting error thrown on catch block saying at line 394 of Model class footerStyleType is String but i checked the json it is int.
This is my get request:

```
    class FormDataAdp extends ChangeNotifier {
  FormListModel formlist;
  String formdatahttpcode = "";

  resetFormDataAdp() {
    formlist = null;
    formdatahttpcode = "";
  }

  refreshdata(String token) {
    resetFormDataAdp();
    notifyListeners();
    getFormList(token);
  }

  getFormList(String token) async {
    try {
      final url = Helper.baseURL + "form-manager-owned/10/false/all?page=1";
      final client = http.Client();
      final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      });
      print(response.body + response.statusCode.toString());
      formdatahttpcode = response.statusCode.toString();
      print(formdatahttpcode);
      notifyListeners();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final parsed = jsonDecode(response.body);
        formlist = FormListModel.fromJson(parsed);
        notifyListeners();
        return formlist;
      } else {
        throw Exception("Unable to fetch the data.");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Model Class which i converted into dart from Json.

```
    class FormListModel {
  Forms forms;
  int totalRecords;
  int totalActiveForms;

  FormListModel({this.forms, this.totalRecords, this.totalActiveForms});

  FormListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    forms = json['forms'] != null ? new Forms.fromJson(json['forms']) : null;
    totalRecords = json['total_records'];
    totalActiveForms = json['total_active_forms'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.forms != null) {
      data['forms'] = this.forms.toJson();
    }
    data['total_records'] = this.totalRecords;
    data['total_active_forms'] = this.totalActiveForms;
    return data;
  }
}

class Forms {
  int currentPage;
  List<Data> data;
  String firstPageUrl;
  int from;
  int lastPage;
  String lastPageUrl;
  List<Links> links;
  String nextPageUrl;
  String path;
  int perPage;
  String prevPageUrl;
  int to;
  int total;

  Forms(
      {this.currentPage,
      this.data,
      this.firstPageUrl,
      this.from,
      this.lastPage,
      this.lastPageUrl,
      this.links,
      this.nextPageUrl,
      this.path,
      this.perPage,
      this.prevPageUrl,
      this.to,
      this.total});

  Forms.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    currentPage = json['current_page'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    firstPageUrl = json['first_page_url'];
    from = json['from'];
    lastPage = json['last_page'];
    lastPageUrl = json['last_page_url'];
    if (json['links'] != null) {
      links = <Links>[];
      json['links'].forEach((v) {
        links.add(new Links.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    nextPageUrl = json['next_page_url'];
    path = json['path'];
    perPage = json['per_page'];
    prevPageUrl = json['prev_page_url'];
    to = json['to'];
    total = json['total'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['current_page'] = this.currentPage;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['first_page_url'] = this.firstPageUrl;
    data['from'] = this.from;
    data['last_page'] = this.lastPage;
    data['last_page_url'] = this.lastPageUrl;
    if (this.links != null) {
      data['links'] = this.links.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['next_page_url'] = this.nextPageUrl;
    data['path'] = this.path;
    data['per_page'] = this.perPage;
    data['prev_page_url'] = this.prevPageUrl;
    data['to'] = this.to;
    data['total'] = this.total;
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String sId;
  bool fieldError;
  String validationError;
  List<String> rules;
  bool ruleApplicable;
  bool ruleConditionApplicable;
  bool isDisabled;
  String group;
  String placeholderValue;
  bool questionLabelHide;
  int formId;
  int id;
  String label;
  String guideLinesForUser;
  int visibleTo;
  bool isRequired;
  int position;
  GeneralOptionClass propertyStaticOptions;
  List<GeneralOptionClass> visibleToOptions;
  int page;
  List<GeneralOptionClass> classificationOptions;
  int classification;
  String fieldName;
  int alignment;
  List<GeneralOptionClass> alignmentOptions;
  bool isHidden;
  String controlType;
  bool active;
  bool editownentry;
  bool enableEditAfterReviewPage;
  bool submitButtonDisabled;
  String isUserAuthenticated;
  List<String> payment;
  bool enableFormFooter;
  int footerType;
  int footerPadding;
  int footerStyleType;
  String footerContent;
  List<String> relationships;
  List<String> formRules;
  bool enableSaveAndResumeLater;
  int fieldSize;
  int fieldHeight;
  bool headerDeleted;
  PageNavigator pageNavigator;
  bool enableClientLogin;
  int entriesCount;
  int clientLoginWith;
  List<GeneralOptionClass> clientLoginWithOptions;
  bool enableReviewPage;
  String reviewPageTitle;
  String reviewPageDescription;
  int buttonStyle;
  List<GeneralOptionClass> buttonStyleOptions;
  String submitButtonText;
  String backButtonText;
  String submitButtonImageURL;
  String backButtonImageURL;
  bool enablePasswordProtection;
  String password;
  bool enableSpamProtection;
  int spamType;
  List<GeneralOptionClass> spamTypeOptions;
  bool limitOneEntryPerIP;
  bool limitOneEntryPerUserId;
  bool limitEntries;
  int maxEntriesLimit;
  bool enableAutomaticScheduling;
  int timeOption;
  List<GeneralOptionClass> timeOptions;
  int formType;
  List<GeneralOptionClass> formTypes;
  String scheduleFromDate;
  String scheduleToDate;
  int dateFormat;
  List<GeneralOptionClass> footerTypeOptions;
  String footerImageUrl;
  int footerImageheight;
  int footerImagewidth;
  List<GeneralOptionClass> footerStyleTypeOptions;
  bool isTemplate;
  bool redirectionSet;
  String redirecturl;
  String redirectionMsg;
  bool redirectPostConfirmation;
  bool showtitledesc;
  String createdBy;
  String updatedBy;
  bool showTimer;
  int leftTime;
  int notifyBefore;
  bool showInternalUsers;
  bool showTimerNotification;
  String timerNotificationMessage;
  bool demandTimerStart;
  int demandTimerPage;
  bool enableAutoSubmitWithTimer;
  String defaultSaveNResumeEmailSubject;
  List<FieldRules> fieldRules;
  bool negativeMarking;
  int negationPercentage;
  List<GeneralOptionClass> fieldSizeOptions;
  String clientid;
  bool published;
  String updatedAt;
  String createdAt;
  String createdByName;
  List<Permissions> permissions;
  int pendingAprovalCount;
  CreatedView createdView;
  List<String> sharedWith;

  Data(
      {this.sId,
      this.fieldError,
      this.validationError,
      this.rules,
      this.ruleApplicable,
      this.ruleConditionApplicable,
      this.isDisabled,
      this.group,
      this.placeholderValue,
      this.questionLabelHide,
      this.formId,
      this.id,
      this.label,
      this.guideLinesForUser,
      this.visibleTo,
      this.isRequired,
      this.position,
      this.propertyStaticOptions,
      this.visibleToOptions,
      this.page,
      this.classificationOptions,
      this.classification,
      this.fieldName,
      this.alignment,
      this.alignmentOptions,
      this.isHidden,
      this.controlType,
      this.active,
      this.editownentry,
      this.enableEditAfterReviewPage,
      this.submitButtonDisabled,
      this.isUserAuthenticated,
      this.payment,
      this.enableFormFooter,
      this.footerType,
      this.footerPadding,
      this.footerStyleType,
      this.footerContent,
      this.relationships,
      this.formRules,
      this.enableSaveAndResumeLater,
      this.fieldSize,
      this.fieldHeight,
      this.headerDeleted,
      this.pageNavigator,
      this.enableClientLogin,
      this.entriesCount,
      this.clientLoginWith,
      this.clientLoginWithOptions,
      this.enableReviewPage,
      this.reviewPageTitle,
      this.reviewPageDescription,
      this.buttonStyle,
      this.buttonStyleOptions,
      this.submitButtonText,
      this.backButtonText,
      this.submitButtonImageURL,
      this.backButtonImageURL,
      this.enablePasswordProtection,
      this.password,
      this.enableSpamProtection,
      this.spamType,
      this.spamTypeOptions,
      this.limitOneEntryPerIP,
      this.limitOneEntryPerUserId,
      this.limitEntries,
      this.maxEntriesLimit,
      this.enableAutomaticScheduling,
      this.timeOption,
      this.timeOptions,
      this.formType,
      this.formTypes,
      this.scheduleFromDate,
      this.scheduleToDate,
      this.dateFormat,
      this.footerTypeOptions,
      this.footerImageUrl,
      this.footerImageheight,
      this.footerImagewidth,
      this.footerStyleTypeOptions,
      this.isTemplate,
      this.redirectionSet,
      this.redirecturl,
      this.redirectionMsg,
      this.redirectPostConfirmation,
      this.showtitledesc,
      this.createdBy,
      this.updatedBy,
      this.showTimer,
      this.leftTime,
      this.notifyBefore,
      this.showInternalUsers,
      this.showTimerNotification,
      this.timerNotificationMessage,
      this.demandTimerStart,
      this.demandTimerPage,
      this.enableAutoSubmitWithTimer,
      this.defaultSaveNResumeEmailSubject,
      this.fieldRules,
      this.negativeMarking,
      this.negationPercentage,
      this.fieldSizeOptions,
      this.clientid,
      this.published,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.createdAt,
      this.createdByName,
      this.permissions,
      this.pendingAprovalCount,
      this.createdView,
      this.sharedWith});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    fieldError = json['fieldError'];
    validationError = json['validationError'];
    if (json['rules'] != null) {
      rules = <String>[];
      json['rules'].forEach((v) {
        rules.add(v);
      });
    }
    ruleApplicable = json['ruleApplicable'];
    ruleConditionApplicable = json['ruleConditionApplicable'];
    isDisabled = json['isDisabled'];
    group = json['group'];
    placeholderValue = json['placeholderValue'];
    questionLabelHide = json['questionLabelHide'];
    formId = json['form_id'];
    id = json['id'];
    label = json['label'];
    guideLinesForUser = json['guideLinesForUser'];
    visibleTo = json['visibleTo'];
    isRequired = json['isRequired'];
    position = json['position'];
    propertyStaticOptions = json['propertyStaticOptions'] != null
        ? new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(json['propertyStaticOptions'])
        : null;
    if (json['visibleToOptions'] != null) {
      visibleToOptions = <GeneralOptionClass>[];
      json['visibleToOptions'].forEach((v) {
        visibleToOptions.add(new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    page = json['page'];
    if (json['classificationOptions'] != null) {
      classificationOptions = <GeneralOptionClass>[];
      json['classificationOptions'].forEach((v) {
        classificationOptions.add(new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    classification = json['classification'];
    fieldName = json['fieldName'];
    alignment = json['alignment'];
    if (json['alignmentOptions'] != null) {
      alignmentOptions = <GeneralOptionClass>[];
      json['alignmentOptions'].forEach((v) {
        alignmentOptions.add(new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    isHidden = json['isHidden'];
    controlType = json['controlType'];
    active = json['active'];
    editownentry = json['editownentry'];
    enableEditAfterReviewPage = json['enableEditAfterReviewPage'];
    submitButtonDisabled = json['submitButtonDisabled'];
    isUserAuthenticated = json['isUserAuthenticated'];
    if (json['payment'] != null) {
      payment = <String>[];
      json['payment'].forEach((v) {
        payment.add(v);
      });
    }
    enableFormFooter = json['enableFormFooter'];
    footerType = json['footerType'];
    footerPadding = json['footerPadding'];
    footerStyleType = json['footerStyleType'];
    footerContent = json['footerContent'];
    if (json['relationships'] != null) {
      relationships = <String>[];
      json['relationships'].forEach((v) {
        relationships.add(v);
      });
    }
    if (json['formRules'] != null) {
      formRules = <String>[];
      json['formRules'].forEach((v) {
        formRules.add(v);
      });
    }
    enableSaveAndResumeLater = json['enableSaveAndResumeLater'];
    fieldSize = json['fieldSize'];
    fieldHeight = json['fieldHeight'];
    headerDeleted = json['headerDeleted'];
    pageNavigator = json['pageNavigator'] != null
        ? new PageNavigator.fromJson(json['pageNavigator'])
        : null;
    enableClientLogin = json['enableClientLogin'];
    entriesCount = json['entriesCount'];
    clientLoginWith = json['clientLoginWith'];
    if (json['clientLoginWithOptions'] != null) {
      clientLoginWithOptions = <GeneralOptionClass>[];
      json['clientLoginWithOptions'].forEach((v) {
        clientLoginWithOptions.add(new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    enableReviewPage = json['enableReviewPage'];
    reviewPageTitle = json['reviewPageTitle'];
    reviewPageDescription = json['reviewPageDescription'];
    buttonStyle = json['buttonStyle'];
    if (json['buttonStyleOptions'] != null) {
      buttonStyleOptions = <GeneralOptionClass>[];
      json['buttonStyleOptions'].forEach((v) {
        buttonStyleOptions.add(new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    submitButtonText = json['submitButtonText'];
    backButtonText = json['backButtonText'];
    submitButtonImageURL = json['submitButtonImageURL'];
    backButtonImageURL = json['backButtonImageURL'];
    enablePasswordProtection = json['enablePasswordProtection'];
    password = json['password'];
    enableSpamProtection = json['enableSpamProtection'];
    spamType = json['spamType'];
    if (json['spamTypeOptions'] != null) {
      spamTypeOptions = <GeneralOptionClass>[];
      json['spamTypeOptions'].forEach((v) {
        spamTypeOptions.add(new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    limitOneEntryPerIP = json['limitOneEntryPerIP'];
    limitOneEntryPerUserId = json['limitOneEntryPerUserId'];
    limitEntries = json['limitEntries'];
    maxEntriesLimit = json['maxEntriesLimit'];
    enableAutomaticScheduling = json['enableAutomaticScheduling'];
    timeOption = json['timeOption'];
    if (json['timeOptions'] != null) {
      timeOptions = <GeneralOptionClass>[];
      json['timeOptions'].forEach((v) {
        timeOptions.add(new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    formType = json['formType'];
    if (json['formTypes'] != null) {
      formTypes = <GeneralOptionClass>[];
      json['formTypes'].forEach((v) {
        formTypes.add(new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    scheduleFromDate = json['scheduleFromDate'];
    scheduleToDate = json['scheduleToDate'];
    dateFormat = json['dateFormat'];
    if (json['footerTypeOptions'] != null) {
      footerTypeOptions = <GeneralOptionClass>[];
      json['footerTypeOptions'].forEach((v) {
        footerTypeOptions.add(new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    footerImageUrl = json['footerImageUrl'];
    footerImageheight = json['footerImageheight'];
    footerImagewidth = json['footerImagewidth'];
    if (json['footerStyleTypeOptions'] != null) {
      footerStyleTypeOptions = <GeneralOptionClass>[];
      json['footerStyleTypeOptions'].forEach((v) {
        footerStyleTypeOptions.add(new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    isTemplate = json['isTemplate'];
    redirectionSet = json['redirectionSet'];
    redirecturl = json['redirecturl'];
    redirectionMsg = json['redirectionMsg'];
    redirectPostConfirmation = json['redirectPostConfirmation'];
    showtitledesc = json['showtitledesc'];
    createdBy = json['createdBy'];
    updatedBy = json['updatedBy'];
    showTimer = json['showTimer'];
    leftTime = json['leftTime'];
    notifyBefore = json['notifyBefore'];
    showInternalUsers = json['showInternalUsers'];
    showTimerNotification = json['showTimerNotification'];
    timerNotificationMessage = json['timerNotificationMessage'];
    demandTimerStart = json['demandTimerStart'];
    demandTimerPage = json['demandTimerPage'];
    enableAutoSubmitWithTimer = json['enableAutoSubmitWithTimer'];
    defaultSaveNResumeEmailSubject = json['defaultSaveNResumeEmailSubject'];
    if (json['fieldRules'] != null) {
      fieldRules = <FieldRules>[];
      json['fieldRules'].forEach((v) {
        fieldRules.add(new FieldRules.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    negativeMarking = json['negativeMarking'];
    negationPercentage = json['negationPercentage'];
    if (json['fieldSizeOptions'] != null) {
      fieldSizeOptions = <GeneralOptionClass>[];
      json['fieldSizeOptions'].forEach((v) {
        fieldSizeOptions.add(new GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    clientid = json['clientid'];
    published = json['published'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    createdByName = json['createdByName'];
    if (json['permissions'] != null) {
      permissions = <Permissions>[];
      json['permissions'].forEach((v) {
        permissions.add(new Permissions.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    pendingAprovalCount = json['pendingAprovalCount'];
    createdView = json['created_view'] != null
        ? new CreatedView.fromJson(json['created_view'])
        : null;
    sharedWith = json['sharedWith'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['_id'] = this.sId;
    data['fieldError'] = this.fieldError;
    data['validationError'] = this.validationError;
    // if (this.rules != null) {
    //   data['rules'] = this.rules.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    // }
    data['ruleApplicable'] = this.ruleApplicable;
    data['ruleConditionApplicable'] = this.ruleConditionApplicable;
    data['isDisabled'] = this.isDisabled;
    data['group'] = this.group;
    data['placeholderValue'] = this.placeholderValue;
    data['questionLabelHide'] = this.questionLabelHide;
    data['form_id'] = this.formId;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['label'] = this.label;
    data['guideLinesForUser'] = this.guideLinesForUser;
    data['visibleTo'] = this.visibleTo;
    data['isRequired'] = this.isRequired;
    data['position'] = this.position;
    if (this.propertyStaticOptions != null) {
      data['propertyStaticOptions'] = this.propertyStaticOptions.toJson();
    }
    if (this.visibleToOptions != null) {
      data['visibleToOptions'] =
          this.visibleToOptions.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['page'] = this.page;
    if (this.classificationOptions != null) {
      data['classificationOptions'] =
          this.classificationOptions.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['classification'] = this.classification;
    data['fieldName'] = this.fieldName;
    data['alignment'] = this.alignment;
    if (this.alignmentOptions != null) {
      data['alignmentOptions'] =
          this.alignmentOptions.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['isHidden'] = this.isHidden;
    data['controlType'] = this.controlType;
    data['active'] = this.active;
    data['editownentry'] = this.editownentry;
    data['enableEditAfterReviewPage'] = this.enableEditAfterReviewPage;
    data['submitButtonDisabled'] = this.submitButtonDisabled;
    data['isUserAuthenticated'] = this.isUserAuthenticated;
    // if (this.payment != null) {
    //   data['payment'] = this.payment.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    // }
    data['enableFormFooter'] = this.enableFormFooter;
    data['footerType'] = this.footerType;
    data['footerPadding'] = this.footerPadding;
    data['footerStyleType'] = this.footerStyleType;
    data['footerContent'] = this.footerContent;
    // if (this.relationships != null) {
    //   data['relationships'] =
    //       this.relationships.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    // }
    // if (this.formRules != null) {
    //   data['formRules'] = this.formRules.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    // }
    data['enableSaveAndResumeLater'] = this.enableSaveAndResumeLater;
    data['fieldSize'] = this.fieldSize;
    data['fieldHeight'] = this.fieldHeight;
    data['headerDeleted'] = this.headerDeleted;
    if (this.pageNavigator != null) {
      data['pageNavigator'] = this.pageNavigator.toJson();
    }
    data['enableClientLogin'] = this.enableClientLogin;
    data['entriesCount'] = this.entriesCount;
    data['clientLoginWith'] = this.clientLoginWith;
    if (this.clientLoginWithOptions != null) {
      data['clientLoginWithOptions'] =
          this.clientLoginWithOptions.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['enableReviewPage'] = this.enableReviewPage;
    data['reviewPageTitle'] = this.reviewPageTitle;
    data['reviewPageDescription'] = this.reviewPageDescription;
    data['buttonStyle'] = this.buttonStyle;
    if (this.buttonStyleOptions != null) {
      data['buttonStyleOptions'] =
          this.buttonStyleOptions.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['submitButtonText'] = this.submitButtonText;
    data['backButtonText'] = this.backButtonText;
    data['submitButtonImageURL'] = this.submitButtonImageURL;
    data['backButtonImageURL'] = this.backButtonImageURL;
    data['enablePasswordProtection'] = this.enablePasswordProtection;
    data['password'] = this.password;
    data['enableSpamProtection'] = this.enableSpamProtection;
    data['spamType'] = this.spamType;
    if (this.spamTypeOptions != null) {
      data['spamTypeOptions'] =
          this.spamTypeOptions.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['limitOneEntryPerIP'] = this.limitOneEntryPerIP;
    data['limitOneEntryPerUserId'] = this.limitOneEntryPerUserId;
    data['limitEntries'] = this.limitEntries;
    data['maxEntriesLimit'] = this.maxEntriesLimit;
    data['enableAutomaticScheduling'] = this.enableAutomaticScheduling;
    data['timeOption'] = this.timeOption;
    if (this.timeOptions != null) {
      data['timeOptions'] = this.timeOptions.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['formType'] = this.formType;
    if (this.formTypes != null) {
      data['formTypes'] = this.formTypes.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['scheduleFromDate'] = this.scheduleFromDate;
    data['scheduleToDate'] = this.scheduleToDate;
    data['dateFormat'] = this.dateFormat;
    if (this.footerTypeOptions != null) {
      data['footerTypeOptions'] =
          this.footerTypeOptions.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['footerImageUrl'] = this.footerImageUrl;
    data['footerImageheight'] = this.footerImageheight;
    data['footerImagewidth'] = this.footerImagewidth;
    if (this.footerStyleTypeOptions != null) {
      data['footerStyleTypeOptions'] =
          this.footerStyleTypeOptions.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['isTemplate'] = this.isTemplate;
    data['redirectionSet'] = this.redirectionSet;
    data['redirecturl'] = this.redirecturl;
    data['redirectionMsg'] = this.redirectionMsg;
    data['redirectPostConfirmation'] = this.redirectPostConfirmation;
    data['showtitledesc'] = this.showtitledesc;
    data['createdBy'] = this.createdBy;
    data['updatedBy'] = this.updatedBy;
    data['showTimer'] = this.showTimer;
    data['leftTime'] = this.leftTime;
    data['notifyBefore'] = this.notifyBefore;
    data['showInternalUsers'] = this.showInternalUsers;
    data['showTimerNotification'] = this.showTimerNotification;
    data['timerNotificationMessage'] = this.timerNotificationMessage;
    data['demandTimerStart'] = this.demandTimerStart;
    data['demandTimerPage'] = this.demandTimerPage;
    data['enableAutoSubmitWithTimer'] = this.enableAutoSubmitWithTimer;
    data['defaultSaveNResumeEmailSubject'] =
        this.defaultSaveNResumeEmailSubject;
    if (this.fieldRules != null) {
      data['fieldRules'] = this.fieldRules.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['negativeMarking'] = this.negativeMarking;
    data['negationPercentage'] = this.negationPercentage;
    if (this.fieldSizeOptions != null) {
      data['fieldSizeOptions'] =
          this.fieldSizeOptions.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['clientid'] = this.clientid;
    data['published'] = this.published;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['createdByName'] = this.createdByName;
    if (this.permissions != null) {
      data['permissions'] = this.permissions.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['pendingAprovalCount'] = this.pendingAprovalCount;
    if (this.createdView != null) {
      data['created_view'] = this.createdView.toJson();
    }
    data['sharedWith'] = this.sharedWith;
    return data;
  }
}

class GeneralOptionClass {
  int id;
  String option;

  GeneralOptionClass({this.id, this.option});

  GeneralOptionClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    option = json['option'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['option'] = this.option;
    return data;
  }
}

}
```

I debugged also but it is still same. Please help. If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: With the help of Postman software double check it or please provide the http response as well.

Comment: This is the filed that i copied from postman: "footerStyleType": 0, It is totally an int.

Comment: which block of code or line gives you the error. try to explicitly convert the data you get from json to int using int.parse(data). you need to import 'dart:convert'; to convert

Comment: If you see my get request there is a try catch block. On catch block it throws an error saying: Type String is not a subtype of int(0n line 394). This is the line 394: footerStyleType = json['footerStyleType']; (footerStyleType is int). Tell me how to fix it.